# how much time does it take for updated keyword to take effect on ios app store search

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I updated my iphone app with new version and added keywords.
Currently new version is ready for sale, but searching by newly added keywords gives no results.
Is there some kind of delay new keyword take effect?

Comment: Yes, there is reported to be a delay, and the reports vary in the amount of delay between various app store servers.

Comment: True, after 1 day all changes took effect.

Answer (score 0):

You have no guarantee that your keywords will rank your app.

Apple raking algorithm takes into account multiple factors. Those factors include the following (my personal analysis):

- Number of downloads per time period;
- Number of ratings per time period and your ratings average;
- App Name & Subtitle;
- Number of users that click on your app listing, related to your app position in the current search;
- Number of users that download your app after clicking on your listing;
- How frequently the app is used by the users that install it and for how long;
- Number of users that delete your app and after how much time;
- Keywords & Description.

Notice that the keywords & description rank last in my opinion.